# Software update error: Package operation failed

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-installation, update-manager, keyrings

Whenever I'm prompted to install software updates, I get the error:

```
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
```

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

this is what the terminal displays:

```
52 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/54.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up apt (0.9.9.1~ubuntu3.2) ...
ERROR: Can't find the archive-keyring
Is the ubuntu-keyring package installed?
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
delia@delia-Inspiron-1764:~$
```

I would appreciate any suggestions/help!  Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome. Someone fixed your problem copying keys from /usr/share/keyrings/  [from a fresh installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129550). Try before `apt-get update` and `apt-get -f install` after `apt-get install ubuntu-keyring` then `dpkg-reconfigure -a`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it didn't seem to work for me.  When I entered the last command, it said it must be run as root.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I'm pretty new to using a terminal, so bare with me!

Comment: Sorry...I was entering it wrong.  I entered it all, but am still getting the same error message.  :/

Comment: Does `dpkg -l | grep -i 'ubuntu-keyring'` return any results?

Comment: delia@delia-Inspiron-1764:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -i 'ubuntu-keyring'
[sudo] password for delia: 
ii  ubuntu-keyring                                2012.05.19                              all          GnuPG keys of the Ubuntu archive